# File Selection from List in a Wizard page

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have a Wizard page which gets a list of IFile. I want to show the user the list and select one file from the list. Then the Wizard returns the selected file.

Is there a standard file chooser that I can use instead of building from scratch in the `createControl()` of the WizardPage? (Maybe something like table view list with scrollbar to show the list.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog` that is a popup displaying any resource wanted, eventually with pre-loaded regexp, allowing to search for file, and you give him a root directory :

[image]

You call `getResult()` to retrieve selection as Object[].

If you want to do just a wizard that does that, then I would do it this way.
If it's a list include in a wizard that does other things, then just list all the files and create a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List`

Answer (score 1):

Though there is no ready-to-use *FileViewer* or the like, you can use a `TableViewer` with a `WorkbenchLabelProvider` to show the list of files.

```java
IFile[] files = ...
TableViewer fileViewer = new TableViewer( parent );
fileViewer.setInput( files );
fileViewer.setContentProvider( ArrayContentProvider.getInstance() );
fileViewer.setLabelProvider( new WorkbenchLabelProvider() );
```

This will create a single-selection table (viewer) that displays the files from the `files` array.

If multi-selection or further styles apply, use `new TableViewer( parent, SWT.MULTI | ... )` to create the viewer.

If the list of files need to be sorted by name or type, you can use the `ResourceComparator` from the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plug-in.

```
fileViewer.setComparator( new ResourceComparator( ResourceComparator.NAME ) );
```

If you don't want the extra plug-in dependency or need to sort by another criteria, it may still be used as a template.